# Transferring tokens to contract B based on contract A's balances mapping

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

Is it possible to snapshot the 'balances' mapping from an old contract ? and give them free new tokens based on the amount in the mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INFO: This is part of my answer posted here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/30509/20808

If you want to retrieve addresses and balances of tokens from old contract, you can do it ONLY if you have implemented the functionnality to get all addresses and their balances in the old contract, something like:

**OLD CONTRACT:**

```
address[] listOfAddresses;
int[] balancesOfAddresses;

    function getAddresses() public returns (address[], int[]){

        return (listOfAddresses, balanceOfAddresses);
    }
```

Or any other way to get this information.

**NEW CONTRACT:**

```
address[] listOfAddresses;
int[] balanceOfAddresses;
function(address[] addresses, int[] balances) public {
    listOfAddresses.push(addresses);
    balanceOfAddresses.push(balances);
}
```

Using this, you could get the information from one contract and push them to an other.

Remark: You could use mapping as well, but I'm not very familiar with them. Remark: If you first contract do not have the capability to retrieve the data, I'm afraid you are stuck. Or maybe if you go through the chain, you could retrieve transactions, but I cannot help on that.

Answer (score 1):

The [MiniMe token](https://github.com/Giveth/minime) does support taking a snapshot at a given block and 'forking' to a new token, maintaining balances from a previous instance.

Comment: it still requires the logic for snapshotting implemented in contract A, so only if minimetoken is contract A

Comment: @NowsyMe If you want to use the balances of an existing contract, you can collect addresses in the Transfer(from,to,amount) event. The augur people have written some scripts to achieve that https://github.com/AugurProject/rep-migration.

Comment: can I ask you to elaborate on this? I look at it, but this require upgradeable path from start as well.

Comment: @NowsyMe No, it doesn't requiere an upgradeable contract. To simplify there's one script that uses Transfer event to collect addresses that sent or received tokens, another calculate balances for each address. Then the addresses are given the calculated balances in the new contract. Finally ensure the total supply is correct. The only thing neede to upgrade from the old contract are Transfer events and read balances both are part of EIP 20 standard.

Comment: Sure, but if a contract is not ERC20 compliant, this is not possible.

Comment: Is it really a token contract? You can check for `transfer` and `transferFrom` calls, this is fine for external owned accounts (check for transaction where 'to' is your contract), but for contracts (ie multisig wallet) you have to use debug.traceTransaction or something like that, because they are "internal transactions".

Comment: I had this one person who created a token contract which ONLY contained a broken transfer function, he was asking how to transfer his balances from that token contract to a new one, which seems impossible to me when it's not even ERC20 compliant